# Can anyone explain why my java code multicast is not working over LAN?

Tags: java, networking, multicast

I have two applications below. I used java `MulticastSocket` to send and receive `DatagramPacket`.

**Sender**

```
public class Sender {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = 5000;
        String group = "225.4.5.6";
        final MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket();
        byte[] buf = new byte[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            buf[i] = (byte) i;
        }
        final DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,
                InetAddress.getByName(group), port);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    s.send(pack);
                    System.out.println("Sent");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Sender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
        //s.close();
    }
}
```

**Receiver**

```
public class Receiver {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = 5000;
        String group = "225.4.5.6";
        MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket(port);
        s.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(group));
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        while (true) {
            s.receive(pack);
            System.out.println("Received data from: " + pack.getAddress().toString()
                    + ":" + pack.getPort() + " with length: "
                    + pack.getLength());
            System.out.write(pack.getData(), 0, pack.getLength());
            System.out.println();
        }
//        s.leaveGroup(InetAddress.getByName(group));
//        s.close();
    }

}
```

This code is work fine when i run it on localhost. But when i try to run it on two different computers over LAN, i can't receive packet.

**I have been turned off the firewall on both computers**

**Can anyone explain why?**

**Edit**

My route table:

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.103     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.103    281
    192.168.0.103  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.103    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.103    281
    192.168.164.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
    192.168.164.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
  192.168.164.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.103    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.103    281
```

Comment: Most firewalls have exception rules. Firewalls can be excessively relied upon; but it's usually a *lot* safer to have a firewall turned on.

Comment: The problem may not be in your code. Have a look at your router's config. It may be disabled there. If you've tampered a lot with your router and it isn't professional grade, you might want to try taking a backup of the settings (there's usually a feature for this), resetting, trying your program, and reinstating your router's config backup.

Comment: I agree entirely with @MotokoKusanagi, but it was still right to test with both firewalls down.

Comment: @Scruffy I think so, but i used my laptop `ad-hoc` to connect two computers peer-to-peer but it still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added routes for multicast addresses? On Linux you have to do as this:

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0/4 eth0
```

(assuming the network interface that connects both machines is eth0)

On Windows, type `route print` at the console (cmd.exe) prompt (you may need administrator priviledges) and check this kind of lines:

```
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En vínculo         127.0.0.1    306
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En vínculo      192.168.56.1    276
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En vínculo    192.168.10.100    266
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En vínculo      192.168.79.1    276
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En vínculo      192.168.34.1    276
```

(this is a spanish machine: "En vínculo" means "linked to")

Windows lists more than one possible route for a multicast packet. The route that is actually used by a sender program is the one with the lowest metric (the last column number). On my setup, it is the route that uses the network interface at `192.168.10.100` (my primary network card).

Check that your machines list their network cards as the lowest metric interface for multicast. You may have `127.0.0.1` as your primary interface for multicast (localhost) instead of your physical network interface.

Also, you may want to test reachability by using the multicast group address `224.0.0.1`. This is the all-hosts multicast group. Any multicast packet is assumed to be able to be received by any host within the same subnet. Check RFC 5771 for more information about multicast address asignment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5771

Beware that multicast works better if both machines are in the same subnet (connected to the same switch, for example). If there is a router in between, things are much more complicated.

Comment: How can i do this on windows?

Comment: In Windows the multicast routes are already defined. Issue a `route print` command from the console and see if there are lines like `224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 ...... ` and the IP address of the net interface you use to connect to the other machine. If it is so, and there is more than one 224..... line, check that the one that list your interface has the lowest metric

Comment: Yes i saw that lines. Should i use `224.0.0.0` address in my code?

Comment: I have edited my post. I have 3 line `224.0.0.0` and my primary interface address is `192.168.0.103`

Comment: So you can see that your multicast packets are not being sent to the desired interface, as the one that has the lowest metric is `192.168.164.1` . Change the metric of the `192.168.0.103` interface from an elevated command prompt as this:
`route change 224.0.0.0/4 192.168.0.103 metric 100`

Comment: Oh it worked. Thank you :). I have one more question, can i change my metric programmatically?